# MAUI blazor image broken not displayed but the file exists in CacheDirectory folder

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

When i try to display an image that is stored in `CacheDirectory` folder it shows a broken image like the screenshot, i checked the path and it is correct the same the image file is good too. i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Windows platform target.

How to display an image stored in `AppDataDirectory` or `CacheDirectory` ?

```
<img src="@Image" width="200" height="200">


@code {
    protected string Image { 
        get => Path.Combine(Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "a.jpeg");
    }
```

The app can access this file because i can open it with `FileStream` and read without issue, so i think the problem is what to put in `<img src`.

`Environment.ContentRootPath` does not exist in MAUI/Blazor, and the file in question will be uploaded at runtime (it is not shipped with the app itself).

Comment: Does it have to be in cachedirectory? Are you able to put it in www folder? then src can point directly

Comment: how ? there is no `Environment.ContentRootPath` in MAUI/Blazor. also i think i have to use those paths instead because on mobile devices not sure if there is a www folder. this file doesn't come with the app but uploaded during run

Comment: You put the image a.jpeg in www/images/ folder and then the razor page do this <img src="images/a.jpeg" />. MAUI Blazor is mobile development for those with Web Blazor experience. There should definitely be a www folder in the project

Comment: ahhhhhh, uploaded.... Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

We can read it into `bytes` and convert it to `base64` string , then show on `img` tag .

Giving that we've put an image called `test.png` in `FileSystem.CacheDirectory` folder.

Sample code:

```
@if (imageSource is not null)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@imageSource" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string? imageSource;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "test.png");
        var imageBytes  = File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
        imageSource = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        imageSource = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is not working, even if it was working it is too much to just display an image in html from it stored folder location. anyone expects a simple solution for a simple problem. i feel like something wrong or missing with MAUI blazor

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Have you got a simper solution?

Comment: I can also confirm this solution doesn't seem to work. Trying to take a photo with the camera - store that image and display it is seeming rediculously difficult!